# Groups with operators $\Omega \ni \omega$ that commute with positive powers, does $(g^{-1})^\omega$ always equal $(g^\omega)^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory

**Do group operators that commute with fixed positive powers necessarily commute with all integer powers as well?**

Let's take a group with operators $(G, \Omega)$ and relax the requirements on each $\omega$ in $\Omega$ so that they are only required commute with raising group elements to powers, namely

$$ (g^n)^\omega = (g^\omega)^n \; \text{for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$} \tag{E1} $$

I'm calling this property *power associativity* in the title for brevity, and it does bear a resemblance to power associative binary operations, but I might be using the term wrong.

Raising group elements to a fixed power ($g \mapsto g^k$ for some fixed $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$) and conjugating by a fixed group element ($g \mapsto h^{-1}gh$ for some fixed $h$) are both examples of a power associative operator. This is my motivation for this question, since raising group elements to fixed powers are not operators in general [under the usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators).

Anyway, I'm curious whether insisting on commuting with powers for positive powers in (E1) is enough to give me (G9) below. I think that commuting with inverses and all positive integers is enough to give me (G9).

$$ (g^a)^\omega = (g^\omega)^a \;\; \text{for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$} \tag{G9} $$

Comment: Isn't the map $g^n \mapsto g^{|n|}$ on an infinite cyclic group a counterexample (or, if you prefer, the map $n \mapsto |n|$ on $({\mathbb Z},+)$).

Comment: @DerekHolt. Yes, it is a counterexample. Thank you.